# send `this` parameter to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have options select (is called `selection`).

when the user change the selected row, there is `onchange` function:

```
<select id="selection" style="width: 276px;" onchange="func(this,'previewBody')">
```

I have a javascript code:

```
var e = document.getElementById("selection");
if ((e.options[i].text).search("5191") != -1) {
      e.selectedIndex = i; // select the row in the option
      //func(this, 'previewBody'); // HERE I have to run this function

}
```

but what should I send? how can I create `this` variable like the `this` of the `onchange` function?

any help appreciated!

Comment: Advise: You shouldn't use the variablename 'e', because it is now a keyword for browsers.

Comment: wouldn't `this` be `e` ?

Comment: @reporter What does `e` refer to?

Comment: var e = document.getElementById("selection");

Comment: @lan it does refer to 'event'

Comment: @reporter: Since when is `e` a keyword?  People just use `e` in event handlers because it's one letter.  You can use anything you want.  I don't think you're right in saying it's a keyword.

Comment: @reporter I doubt that. `event` is the keyword, not `e`. People use `e` as a shorthand in event handlers, but browsers don't use `e`

Comment: @reporter but you can define any variable name to `event`

Comment: @JoeFrambach --You fooled me there for a sec. See the .search() call? That's jQuery. Not massively jQ, but indicates that it's available.-- Scratch that, it's not jQuery at all. My mistake.

Comment: @MaximKumpan isn't that normal JavaScript?

Comment: @MaximKumpan: No it isn't.  `e.options[i].text` is a string.  Strings have a `.search` method.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: @MaximKumpan Really? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Comment: I think I read it somewhere, because lots of users had used e instead of event -in plain javascript- so the bowser manufactors adapted it too

Comment: Whoops. Sorry, end of the day - attention wandering. Yes, it's not jQuery.

Comment: Where is the rest of your function (particularly, the part that defines the function arguments)?

Comment: @reporter: I'm curious where you read that.  Because the only "global" event object is `window.event` (not `window.e`), which is only used in IE.  All other browsers pass the `event` object to the handler as a parameter.  The de facto argument name is `e`, but that's nothing "official".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the name of the variable holding the element:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("selection");
if ((elem.options[i].text).search("5191") != -1) {
    elem.selectedIndex = i;
    func(elem, "previewBody");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The "this" in your onchange declaration will be the select box whose ID is "selection".  Therefore, if you pass "e" you should have an equivalent call.